# Fetching the table using pandas with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=SBILIFE"
driver.get(url)

expiry = "29-Jul-2021"
```

I want to click on "Option Chain" and I want to fetch all the data in the table into dataframe. I want to run and fetch the data every 30 secs.

Problem is, If I use,

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=SBILIFE')
```

But, this link will not fetch proper table because proper table is in Option Chain tab. So, I have to use selenium.

Is there any easy way to fetch the option chain table?

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Option Chain').click()` and then `table = driver.find_element_by_id('optionChainTable-equity')`

Comment: It says, selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException for driver.find_element_by_link_text('Option Chain').click()

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the "All Historical Data" tab select Year and expiry date and then download CSV. You can automate this part with selenium.

EDIT:

You can open the developer console look at the network tab.

You will find a request (marked) which gets the above table in JSON format.
You don't have to use selenium. Simple `requests.get` will do just fine. You can make a request with these headers and you will get the json.

[image: Request desciption]

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to fetch realtime data with 30 secs of interval which cannot be found in the historical data

Comment: @sam
 please check now.

Comment: what I am saying is, it's not possible to get history data of 30-sec interval. It can only fetch historical data with 1 d interval. Can you please show me a test code that can fetch 30-sec data for 6 months of any stock?